# Integrate Spring-based java module into a standalone java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring-based module that I need to integrate with an existing/legacy Java "standalone" app. The Spring-based module is a simple implementation of an **AuthenticationProvider** (spring-security).

What I would like to do is hook up the spring based module in a Java application in a way that I can simply call the authenticate method on that provider from the Java code.

Is that possible? What is required?

Is it possible to wrap the spring module in a plain Java library and use that as API interface for my standalone Java app?

I already searched for specific tutorials but it seems there isn't one that fit this requirement.

Comment: Try: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/reference/technical-overview.html

Comment: @James not exactly what I am looking for but usefully anyway

Comment: since we do not have an option to say what would a login view or dafault-view or login-success-view, a full-fledged support from spring-security cannot be expected. We would need to build the funcationality on our own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have to use the **ApplicationContext** directly so I can manage the Spring framework in my application.

```java
public class MyApplication {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext springApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            MySpringConfiguration.class)) {
        springApplicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
        authProvider = springApplicationContext.getBean(MyAuthenticationProvider.class);
    }

    Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("foo", "foo");
    Authentication result = authProvider.authenticate(request);

    if (result.isAuthenticated()) {
        LOGGER.debug("User is authenticated");
    } else {
        LOGGER.debug("Cannot authenticate user.");
    }

}
```